# How to set up a Linear Programming Problem with lpSolveAPI in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm running into a problem setting up a linear programming problem in R using `lpSolveAPI`.

I have up to seven decision variables and would like to select the variables that maximize a linear reward function within some budget. An additional constraint is added that determines if a particular variable is able to be selected.

```
# set the minimum number of variables to be chosen
min_select <- 3
# set a budget
budget <- 381
# set a cost for each variable, incurred if selected
costs <- c(4289.31047,   36.80011,  247.96872, 5493.60997,   59.53517,   36.80011, 5984.42040)
# set an availabiliy vector. When a value is 1, that variable can be selected. If 0, it cannot
var_availability <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
# set the reward function coefficients
rewards <- c(1.78341784, 0.07973014, 0.45745560, 1.84883011, 0.17699768, 0.12815014, 2.65000395)
```

I have tried to set up a function that returns the result vector that denotes which variables are selected. If the problem is infeasible due to the constraints, I want it to print out how much the budget would need to be increased to make the problem feasible.

```
get_lp_result <- function(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
{
  var_count <- length(var_availability)
  # set up with constraints, +2 for the budget and availability constraints
  my.lp <- make.lp(var_count+2, var_count)
  reward <- matrix(rewards, nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)
  # determines what variables can be selected
  selection_coeff <- matrix(rep(1, times=length(var_availability)), nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)
  costs <- matrix(costs, nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)
  
  # set budget constraint
  set.row(my.lp, 1, selection_coeff)
  set.row(my.lp, 2, costs)

  # set availability constraints
  diag.mat <- diag(1, nrow=length(var_availability), ncol=length(var_availability))
  for(i in 1:length(var_availability))
  {
    set.row(my.lp, i+2, diag.mat[i,])
  }
  
  # set objective function
  set.objfn(my.lp, rewards)
  set.type(my.lp, 1:length(reward), "binary")
  
  # set equality symbols
  eq <- rep("<=", times=var_count + 2) # + 2 for constraints
  # set the first eq. to ensure minimum number of variables is selected
  eq[1] <- ">="
  set.constr.type(my.lp, eq)
  
  # set RHS of the equation
  set.rhs(my.lp, c(min_select, budget, var_availability))
  
  delay=30
  # set to maximize criticality scores
  lp.control(my.lp, timeout=delay, sense="max") # set timeout reset in seconds
  solve(my.lp)
  result <- get.variables(my.lp)
  ## write the model to file to review
  write.lp(my.lp,'_lp_model_setup.lp',type='lp')
  # if an optimal result isn't obtained, looks at the duals
  if(sum(result) == 0)
  {
    sens <- get.sensitivity.rhs(my.lp)
    # is this the additional value that needs to be added to the budget
    # in order to meet the constraints?
    return(print(paste("Budget needs to increase by", sens$dualstill[2])))
  }else
  {
    return(result)
  }
}
```

With this initial setup everything seems to be working:

```
result <- get_lp_result(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
# min number of selections constraint is met
result
[1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
# budget constraint is met
sum(costs*result)
[1] 344.304
# availability constraint is met
(var_availability - result >= 0)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

If I increase the minimum variable selection constraint for the problem to become infeasible, the output indicates how much more the budget must increase:

```
min_select <- 4

get_lp_result(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
[1] "Budget needs to increase by 0.104109999999262"
```

If I go ahead and increase the budget accordingly, I get a feasible result that meets the constraints:

```
budget <- budget + 0.11
get_lp_result(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
[1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

All seems to be working. However, if I continue to increase the minimum variable selection constraint, I get a non-sensical result:

```
min_select <- 6
get_lp_result(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
[1] "Budget needs to increase by 15767.3349499933"
```

The above doesn't make sense because the sum of the cost of the six lowest cost variables is less than the budget increase above:

```
sum(costs[order(costs)[1:6]])
[1] 10164.02
```

I shouldn't need a budget above this amount to get a feasible solution. If I increase the budget to exactly the cost of the six lowest cost variables, I get a feasible result, which contradicts the previously reported necessary budget increase:

```
budget <- sum(costs[order(costs)[1:6]])
get_lp_result(min_select, budget, costs, var_availability, rewards)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Obviously, I'm either setting up the problem incorrectly or misinterpreting the sensitivity results. How should this problem be set up?

Comment: Note that sensitivity analysis is only available for pure, continuous LPs. Your model has binary variables.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelahen is there another way to determine the budget increase necessary?

Comment: Use an elastic formulation where you can increase the budget but at a hefty price.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelager I’m assuming you mean at a hefty increase in compute time? Or do you literally mean increase the budget itself?

Comment: Increase the budget. An extra dollar costs n dollars where n is large.